# Reading in extended ASCII with cin.get()

Tags: c++, ascii, cin

I am trying to read in single extended ASCII characters with `cin.get()`.  I want to use `cin.get()` so that I can also read in spaces, etc in the input.  I figured out that I need to use unsigned chars to store the characters but unsigned chars and `cin.get()` do not seem to work together.  Is there a way to do this?

Basically, I've been trying to do something like this:

```
unsigned char c;
while (cin.get(c))
{
   //do stuff with c
   ....
}
```

Comment: You don't need to declare c as `unsigned char` in order for you to be able to work with ascii code 0..255

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Is there a way to do this?**

Try this

```
 unsigned char c;
    while ( (c = cin.get()) != EOF )

        {

          //do some stuff 

        }
```

You can try one more thing to read the 255 ASCII characters :

```
int ch;
unsigned char c;

while ( (ch = cin.get()) != EOF )

      {
        c = (unsigned char)(ch);

        // do some stuff 
      }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it just loops

Comment: @Mark You have to use EOF according to your system `ctrl+Z` on windows ( I am not too sure of it ) look for it on net. Otherwise to just check that it works you can use `'\n'` or any other character for that matter instead of EOF